# Creating table for JSON multidimensional array

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I have my JSON here:

```
{
"orders": [
    {
        "orderNumber": "ORDER_900123",
        "orderDate": "2014-08-28T17:10:10Z",
        "orderType": "OR",
        "customerId": "19827",
        "poNumber": "PO_12345",
        "deliveries": [
            {
                "deliveryNumber": "D1.2",
                "shipDate": "2014-10-10T12:10:00Z",
                "devices": [
                    {
                        "deviceId": "1111",
                        "assetTag": "A123456"
                    },
                    {
                        "deviceId": "2222",
                        "assetTag": "A123456"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "deliveryNumber": "D2.2",
                "shipDate": "2019-10-10T12:10:00Z",
                "devices": [
                    {
                        "deviceId": "3333",
                        "assetTag": "A123456"
                    },
                    {
                        "deviceId": "4444",
                        "assetTag": "A123456"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
],
"statusCode": "COMPLETE",
"respondedOn": "2014-10-17T07:22:53Z"
}
```

I am trying to create a table for this JSON using $.each loop. Situation is that "deliveries" and "devices" number of array will always be changing except for "orders" which is only will be 1 array.

Here's what I have so far, since "orders" array will always be 1 I'll just put their key and value in var and echo them out later:

```
$.getJSON("sodresponse.json", function(data){
    var statusCode = data.statusCode;
    var respondedOn = data.respondedOn;
    var orderNumber = data.orders[0].orderNumber;
    var orderDate = data.orders[0].orderDate;
    var orderType = data.orders[0].orderType;
    var customerId = data.orders[0].customerId;
    var deliveries = '';
    var devices = '';

    $.each(data.orders[0].deliveries, function(key, value){
        deliveries += '<tr>';
        deliveries += '<th>Delivery No:</th>';
        deliveries += '<td>'+value.deliveryNumber+'</td>';
        deliveries += '</tr>';
        deliveries += '<tr>';
        deliveries += '<th>Ship Date:</th>';
        deliveries += '<td>'+value.shipDate+'</td>';
        deliveries += '</tr>';
        deliveries += '<tr>';
        deliveries += '<th>Device ID:</th>';
        deliveries += '<td>'+value.devices.deviceId+'</td>';
        deliveries += '</tr>';
        deliveries += '<tr>';
        deliveries += '<th>Asset Tag:</th>';
        deliveries += '<td>'+value.devices.assetTag+'</td>';
        deliveries += '</tr>';
    });

    $.each(data.orders[0].deliveries.devices, function(key, value){
        devices += '<tr>';
        devices += '<th>Device ID</th>';
        devices += '<td>'+value.deviceId+'</td>';
        devices += '</tr>';
        devices += '<tr>';
        devices += '<th>Asset Tag</th>';
        devices += '<td>'+value.assetTag+'</td>';
        devices += '</tr>';
    });
});
$('#sodtable').append(deliveries);
```

My desired output is like this:

```
Delivery No: D1.2
    Ship Date: 2014-10-10T12:10:00Z
        Device ID: 1111
        Asset Tag: A123456
        Device ID: 2222
        Asset Tag: A123456
Delivery No: D.2
    Ship Date: 2019-10-10T12:10:00Z
        Device ID: 3333
        Asset Tag: A123456
        Device ID: 4444
        Asset Tag: A123456
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try following code, You need to add `devices` loop inside current loop of `deliveries`

```
$.getJSON("sodresponse.json", function(data){
    var statusCode = data.statusCode;
    var respondedOn = data.respondedOn;
    var orderNumber = data.orders[0].orderNumber;
    var orderDate = data.orders[0].orderDate;
    var orderType = data.orders[0].orderType;
    var customerId = data.orders[0].customerId;
    var deliveries = '';
    var devices = '';  
    $.each(data.orders[0].deliveries, function(key, value){
        deliveries += '<tr>';
        deliveries += '<th>Delivery No:</th>';
        deliveries += '<td>'+value.deliveryNumber+'</td>';
        deliveries += '</tr>';
        deliveries += '<tr>';
        deliveries += '<th>Ship Date:</th>';
        deliveries += '<td>'+value.shipDate+'</td>';
        deliveries += '</tr>';


        $.each(value.devices, function(key1, value1){
          console.log(value1.deviceId);
        deliveries += '<tr>';
        deliveries += '<th>Device ID</th>';
        deliveries += '<td>'+value1.deviceId+'</td>';
        deliveries += '</tr>';
        deliveries += '<tr>';
        deliveries += '<th>Asset Tag</th>';
        deliveries += '<td>'+value1.assetTag+'</td>';
        deliveries += '</tr>';

    });
         deliveries += '<tr><td colspan="2"></td></tr>';
    });


    $('#sodtable').append(deliveries);
});
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/hks6ep42/)

Comment: I did try adding devices loop inside deliveries loop but I was using 
    $.each(data.orders[0].deliveries.devices, function(key, value){
No wonder it wont work since it'll be reading from data all over again.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Glad to help @KuSyafiq